# perl beginner on windows - problems executing perl -n -e in windows command prompt

Tags: windows, perl, strawberry-perl

I use W7 64bit and I just installed strawberry perl. I need to execute a simple script from windows command line for manipulation of text files:

```
perl -ne 'chomp; print "$_ O O O O\n"' test.txt > textformatted.txt
```

I get error:

```
Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.
```

It's in the `PATH` and also I can call `perl -v`. I tried adding spaces, replacing `'` with `"`, backslashs etc. but no use.

I looked at tutorials and searched on the web and I found a lot of statements like this so it seems that this statement should work. But it doesn't.

Can somebody please help me? Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your single quotes to double quotes.

```
perl -ne "chomp; print qq($_ O O O O\n)" test.txt > textformatted.txt
```

Comment: Thank you! So I can always put qq() on stuff that should be under quotes?

Comment: Yes.  Since the shell (i.e., cmd.exe) uses the double quotes for its quoting, you'll need to use either qq(..) or a heredoc when you need double quoted string var interpolation in oneliners.